# inserting unicode characters into mysql database shows ??????? in field

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys I am having trouble trying to convert my web app to support unicode characters. I have the following script which tries to insert russian characters into my mysql database but just outputs ?????? in my mysql database field. I have changed default charset to UTF-8 in my php.ini and have modified my table fields to collation: utf8_unicode_ci. Anyone have any ideas?

```
mb_language('uni'); mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

                $sql = 'SET NAMES utf8';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt->execute();

$sql = 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt->execute();

$sql = 'INSERT INTO topic (topic_id,topic_title) VALUES (?,?)';
$stmt6 = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt6->execute(array(0,"дравствуйте"));
?>
```

**show create table edit**

```
CREATE TABLE `topic` (
 `id` mediumint(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `topic_title` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,

 `description` mediumtext CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,

 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `description` (`description`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `topic_title` (`topic_title`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `topic_title_2` (`topic_title`,`description`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `description_2` (`description`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=39 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: where are you seeing the question marks?

Comment: in the field topic_title in my mysql database where I am trying to insert the characters. When I echo those characters, they come out fine in php though.

Comment: Confused... you're seeing the question marks in your MySql CLIENT, but the data is proper unicode and prints fine through PHP when queried from the database?

Comment: no lol, sorry, when I view the fields in phpmyadmin, in the field where the unicode should be, it shows ???????, but when I echo those characters just in php (no query) they show. I was just trying to emphasize that the php configuration seems to be fine.

Comment: I have found that UTF-8 works fine without using the mb_ functions and without calling SET NAMES. Your PHP and MySQL do not necessarily need to even know that you're using UTF-8 at all. You just have to make sure the browser does, as Wrikken has noted.

Comment: when I remove those, I just get Ð´Ñ€Ð°Ð²ÑÑ‚Ð²ÑƒÐ¹Ñ‚Ðµ in my database

Comment: You could verify that MySQL is storing the proper characters by dumping the db/table using mysqldump, then viewing the dump file with a hex editor. If the proper hex values are present, then it's just a display issue.

Comment: What does your 'SHOW CREATE TABLE topic;' look like? As I get the distinct impression the topic_title has another charset....

Comment: see the show create above Wrikken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work by using the following sql:

```
ALTER DATABASE mydatabase charset=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, (if this you're quoting file is also in utf-8) the PHP & MySQL side is OK, but the HTTP / HTML side of things isn't.

- Do you send a `Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8` header?
- Is there a `<meta>` element on the HTML page that claims another charset then utf-8?

---

So, after more infomation: in 'normal' PHP scripts it works I gather (?), in PHPMyAdmin it doesn't (which should make it more of a candidate for superuser.com b.t.w.). A version of PHPMyAdmin used would be nice, but normally, a `$cfg['DefaultCharset'] = 'utf-8';` in PHPMyAdmin config should work if the rest of non-PHPMyAdmin script works. If not: update to the latest PHPMyAdmin release, and if it still doesn't work file a bug report.

Comment: I have the meta element, but when you say header, how do you modify your http setting?

Comment: The 'default_charset' setting should normally do, but it can't hurt to double check (for instance with LiveHTTPHeaders in Firefox).

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing those `??????` on mysql browser or on mysql cli, make sure you tune up the charset settings on the programs, even if the entries are correctly added to the database, displaying them correctly also depends on the client charset settings.

Comment: that is true, but they are not displaying correctly in database, first it was ???????, then I removed mb_functions and calling set names like Mark mentioned and now it is Ð´Ñ€Ð°Ð²ÑÑ‚Ð²ÑƒÐ¹Ñ‚Ðµ in database

Answer (score 0):

I'm inclined to think the problem isn't with MySQL.

You are entering an non ASCII string as a literal into a PHP script. Are you sure the  "дравствуйте" string will be sent to MySQL server as UTF-8 encoded?

I've seen some problems with nos ASCII characters with PHP and MySQL with incompatible charset configurations amongst the operating system, the PHP interpreter (it inherits the default from the operating system), the database and the development tools (the encoding of .php files). If all four are configured to the same encoding, it should work.

You said that your php.ini is configured to UTF-8. If your source php file isn't in UTF-8, it will not work! So, check if your php files are encoded as UTF-8 and if the mysql client is configured to UTF-8 too.

A common mistake is to forget to configure the MySQL client to UTF-8 too and fail to check the data on the database because of charset problems with MySQL client application.

Home it helps!

Comment: When I said show create database, it stated ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=39 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1, could this be a problem? Also when you mentioned converting a php file to utf-8, what exactly do you mean. Thanks again axmachado

Answer (score 0):

From PHPMYADMIN please change the Collation to utf32_general_ci, they will support and some cases it will make existing "????" to correct one as well.

[PHP Myadmin illustration purpose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7iop.png)

Answer (score -1):

**DB Activity for Storing Emojis**

1) default-character-set = utf8mb4 under [client]

2) default-character-set = utf8mb4 under [mysql]

3) Following under [mysqld]
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
character-set-server = `utf8mb4`
collation-server = `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

4) Restart Mysql server using below command

```
     `sudo service mysql stop`
     `sudo service mysql start`
```

5) ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

6) ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

7) SET NAMES utf8mb4;

Comment: Can you please add explanation how this address the issue?

Comment: this is unrelated to the old question at all.